# How to exclude <xyz>.class while searching a file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When ever I try to search any file in my project in Android Studio along with that file, I also get .class in the result. I want to exclude all those file.
Can any one help me where I need to do the changes in .iml file of project in Android Studio to remove these .class file from search result

Comment: What do you mean be search ? Do you mean the 'Find in path' or the 'double shift' search ?

Comment: @Henry searching for a file in code base, for example searching for mainActivity.java file in my android project in Android Studio

Comment: I get that, but how do you search? I use 'Search Everywhere' option to search for a file in the code base. Tap shift twice and type in 'mainActivity', this shows only the .java file and not the .class file.